# Create a real-time, timed, and synchronized sequence of events for all users in flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Is there any way, maybe using flask-socketio or something, to create an app where, no matter what time the user goes to the app, the same sequence of events is taking place? For example think of YouTube live streams. Everyone sees the same thing at the same time and hears the same thing at the same time.

Let's say I want to animate, using JavaScript, a bunch of airplanes taking off with sound at a certain time and date. The event should start at the specified time and date. Regardless of when the user joins (on or after the time and date), the airplanes should all be in the same location and all users should be seeing and hearing the same thing. Is there any way to do this? Can someone please guide me with an introduction on what steps to take to learn how to do this?

Comment: Your best bet in this kind of scenario would be to research multiplayer games and learn about the patterns and tools developers use there to keep gameplay in sync. What you are asking about is not technology-specific, it's more about patterns. The pub/sub pattern is likely going to play a large role in your solution, so that's a good place to start.

Comment: Is there no way of doing it with socket.io and flask, or some kind of timing of functions?

Comment: One way to do this is with streaming. Maybe a webcam implementation would help? https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-video-streaming-revisited

Comment: I don't see how I would need a webcam for this. Is there no way to call a function at a specific time and date, and send the socket.io data which contains the animation values?